# How do I input an integer into an array with strcat and sprintf?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, strcat

I'm trying to create a chess visualization using a 2d array and for loops. My plan is to first initialize an array with the horizontal alphabets like this:

```
char array1[8] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'};
```

Then, I will combine all of this alphabets with a chessboard.

```
{a8 b8 c8...
 a7 b7 c7...
 ...
}
```

This is the code that I made to try doing so:

```cpp
int i,j;
char chessboard[8][8];
for (i = 8; i >= 0; i--) {
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    char buffer[1];
    chessboard[i][j] = array1[j];
    sprintf(buffer, "%d" , i); 
    strcat(&chessboard[i][j], buffer);
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work when I try to print them like this:

```
for (i = 8; i >=0; i--) {
  for(j=0; j < 8; j++) {
    printf("%c ", chessboard[i][j]);
    if(j == 7)
      printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: First thing I noticed: in `for (i = 8; i >= 0; i--)` your `i` will have 9 values ,,, `8`, `7`, `6`, `5`, `4`, `3`, `2`, `1`, and `0`

Comment: `chessboard` is an 8x8 array of single `char` values, not strings.  Instead of this complicated rigmarole, just do `chessboard[i][j] = '0' + i;`

Comment: my 2 cents. for (i = 8; i >=0; i--); <=== In C Array index starts at 0 not 1. So you have to modify the initial value of i from 8 to 7.

Comment: @pmg  Oh I didn't realize I still include  = there, thanks for that

Comment: @BEPP yup, I didn't realize the = there my bad

Comment: @paddy Thanks!! I'll try to do that once I get home.

Comment: Why don't you try to name your loop variables `row` and `col`?  Probably you'll get to the problem you are having yourself.  Good identifier selection is a task that most programmers fail at first... It requires some training... but once you get to it, it takes you off of many mistakes.

Comment: BTW, _it doesn't seem to work_ is not a useful description on what the code is supposed (you suppose) it is doing.  Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to be easy to know what the problem you can be having.  On my side I see a couple of them, at least.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution to your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BOARD_SIZE    (8)
void print_board(void)
{
    int row;
    for (row = BOARD_SIZE; row > 0; row--) {
        char *sep = "";
        int col;
        for (col = 'a'; col < 'a' + BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
            printf("%s%c%d", sep, col, row);
            sep = " ";
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    print_board();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

will output:

```
$ a.out
a8 b8 c8 d8 e8 f8 g8 h8
a7 b7 c7 d7 e7 f7 g7 h7
a6 b6 c6 d6 e6 f6 g6 h6
a5 b5 c5 d5 e5 f5 g5 h5
a4 b4 c4 d4 e4 f4 g4 h4
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 f3 g3 h3
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 f2 g2 h2
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1
$ _
```

By the way, you cannot use neither `strcat()` nor `sprintf()` to write into a `char [][]` 2D array of chars.  Either function stores strings (which is a sequence of chars **ended in a `\0`** character delimiter)  Each array cell has only space for **one** character, and you plan to put **three** (the letter, the digit, and the `\0` delimiter)

Have you declared your board as:

```
char chessboard[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE][3];
```

then you can write:

```
    int row;
    for(row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
        int col;
        for (col = 0; col < BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
            snprintf(chessboard[row][col], 
                     sizeof chessboard[row][col],
                     "%c%d", 'a' + col, row + 1);
        }
    }
```

and now each cell has space to hold a full string of two characters plus the final `\0`.  This will assign the white square `a1` to the cell `[0][0]`, this is the lower left corner, the `h1` square to cell `[0][7]`, the
`a8` to cell `[7][0]` and the `h8` to `[7][7]`.  (the row goes up from 0 to 7, the cols go left to rigth, from 0 to 7.  If this is not what you want, probably you'll have no problem in *turning it otherwise*.

Programming is like sculpturing.  First make a *draft* and then, go refining it once and another, until you get something that satisfies you.  Don't try to get it all at once.  And name variables properly!!!! :)  This not only helps you, but also to your code readers.